# Linq to XML - get elements that have certain child element

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

Using LINQ to XML, how do I get a collection of all elements that have a named child element.

for example;

```
<root>
  <Garage>
   <Car id="001">
    <Price PaymentType="Cash">$100</Price>
   </Car>
   <Car id="002">
    <Price PaymentType="Cash">$200</Price>
   </Car>
  <Car id="003">
  </Car>
 </Garage>
</root>
```

this will return 2 Car elements (#1 and #2) as they have the Price element. It won't return Car #3, as it doesn't have a price element.

thanks as always

Comment: All the things I've tried so far return the child elements. I'll have another go and post a code sample if/when I get stuck again

Comment: Without seeing your code, we have to resort to guessing at where you might be stuck. I'd recommend finding all of the Car elements. Once you do that, try to remove the ones without Price children. Once you've done that, try to combine the two steps into a single query. Good luck!

Comment: I've not been able to solve this using Linq to XML. However, I solved it by iterating through the list of XElements and filtering that way.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an XDocument object named doc with your example xml loaded into it.  You could try something like this.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> elements = doc.Descendants("Garage").Elements().Where(e => e.Elements().Any());
```